# Three.js ShaderMaterial issue with lights

Tags: javascript, three.js

Helo, here's part of my code - earth globe :)

```
    function createGlobe(){
        var normalMap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("images/earth_normal_2048.jpg");
        var surfaceMap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("images/earth_surface_2048.jpg");
        var specularMap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("images/earth_specular_2048.jpg");

        var shader = THREE.ShaderLib["phong"];
        var uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone(shader.uniforms);

        uniforms["tNormal"] = {type:"t", value:normalMap};
        uniforms["tDiffuse"] = {type:"t", value:surfaceMap};
        uniforms["tSpecular"] = {type:"t", value:specularMap};

        //uniforms["enableDiffuse"] = true;
        //uniforms["enableSpecular"] = true;

        var shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
            fragmentShader:shader.fragmentShader,
            vertexShader:shader.vertexShader,
            uniforms:uniforms,
            lights:false
            });

        var globeGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1,32,32);

        //tangents are needed for the shader
        globeGeometry.computeTangents();

        globe = new THREE.Mesh(globeGeometry, shaderMaterial);

        globe.rotation.z = 0.41;

        earthgroup.add(globe);

        }
```

The problematic spot is at ShaderMaterial parameter "lights:true", when set there is following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined three.js:23875
refreshUniformsLights three.js:23875
setProgram three.js:23593
renderBuffer three.js:22018
renderObjects three.js:22689
render three.js:22563
render Earth-clouds.html:100
wrappedCallback
```

which is

```
function refreshUniformsLights ( uniforms, lights ) {

        uniforms.ambientLightColor.value = lights.ambient;
                ....
}
```

and that seems to me that lights are not defined? Well I got them.
When I set lights:false it renders the globe with the default material. It looks like a bug  that could by in my code :-)

Comment: You have the wrong syntax to define a uniform. See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Uniforms-types. For eg, if you want to define a texture map uniform parameter, do: `uniforms['mymap'] = { type: "t", value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "texture.jpg" ) }`

Comment: I updated the uniforms syntax. Not sure if it allright now. The error is the same.

Comment: You did not update enableDiffuse / enableSpecular. However, I'm not sure those are uniforms, as the boolean type does not exist for uniforms...

Comment: Yes, I don't see boolean flag in uniforms neither. But there must be something with my code. Here's the link and please checkout the errors in console https://googledrive.com/host/0B5WTRqdgf9Nna25iMVlXZ3pQQlU/Earth-clouds.html I have set the uniforms directly to shader.uniforms, so   I guess it must be something other for now  TypeError: uniforms.ambientLightColor is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

uniforms.ambientLightColor.value = lights.ambient;

Comment: That's simply that `ambientLightColor` does not exist as a uniform parameter. Print the `uniforms` collection and see what you can find in it. Maybe you should use `phong` instead of `normal` to get your shader...

Comment: Change to `lights:false` in your shader, the shader your are using does not have the necessary data to be used when `lights=true`

Comment: I thought it's looking for scene lights. With "phong" there were some other errors. The normal material is not used.

Comment: Got the same error while enabling lights in the ShaderMaterial, putting manually the uniforms (ambientLightColor, ...) removed the error yet the issue is not fixed as the uniforms aren't updated.