# Using lights in three.js shader

Tags: three.js, shader

I'm trying to access the scene's lights from a shader in three.js.

This question is nearly a duplicate of [Three.js ShaderMaterial issue with lights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508280/three-js-shadermaterial-issue-with-lights)
but the comments on that question aren't helping me resolve the issue.

Here is the vertex shader:

```
#if NUM_DIR_LIGHTS > 0
    struct DirectionalLight {
        vec3 direction;
        vec3 color;
        int shadow;
        float shadowBias;
        float shadowRadius;
        vec2 shadowMapSize;
     };
     uniform DirectionalLight directionalLights[ NUM_DIR_LIGHTS ];
#endif
  varying vec3 color;
  void main() {
     float r = directionalLights[0].color.r;
     color = vec3(r,1.0,0.0);
     gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position , 1.0);
  }
```

and the relevant ShaderMaterial:

```
var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: THREE.UniformsLib['lights'],
    vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexShader').innerHTML,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentShader').innerHTML,
    lights : true
  });
```

I've posted the entire example code here: https://jsfiddle.net/zhkvcajs/

Removing the `lights : true` renders a green knot, but it's not getting the `directionalLights` information that should change the knot's color.  Apparently, `lights : true` is required for that, but causes an error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use scene lights with `ShaderMaterial`, you need to set `lights: true`.

```
var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
    uniforms: uniforms,
    vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexShader').innerHTML,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentShader').innerHTML,
    lights: true
} );
```

three.js r.126

Comment: So, I did have the `THREE.UniformsLib[ "lights" ]` as uniforms, but hadn't included the `THREE.UniformsLib[ "ambient" ]`.  It seems highly non-discoverable that to use lights, you need something else besides lights.  If you cannot use lights without ambient, then why aren't the ambient uniforms simply part of the lights uniforms?

Comment: I think one could make a reasonable argument that this is a bug.

Comment: Fixed in r.75dev. `"ambient"` uniforms have been merged into `"lights"` uniforms.

Comment: Awesome, WL.  I'm in the middle of the semester and was going to put together a bug report as soon as I had a moment to breathe.  I appreciate your answer and the new fix!