# three.js .png image renders white and not as it should

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, png, glsl

I am trying to get a .obj to render with a .png texture, however when I put the .png texture, the head turns white as seen here:

[White headed avatar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDlPa.png)

However when I remove the png texture it looks like this:

This is what I am using to create the texture:

```
    <script id="vertex_shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main() {

    vUv = uv;

   gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );

   }

  </script>

  <script id="fragment_shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

   uniform vec3 color;
 uniform sampler2D texture;

   varying vec2 vUv;

 void main() {

 vec4 tColor = texture2D( texture, vUv );

gl_FragColor = vec4( mix( color, tColor.rgb, tColor.a ), 1.0 );

}
```

```
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('./Avatar/FaceTestTr.png'); 
texture.needsUpdate = true;
var uniforms = {
    color: { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color( 0xffffff ) }, // material is "red"
    texture: { type: "t", value: texture },
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.9,
};

var AvatarTextureF = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: uniforms,
    vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertex_shader' ).textContent,
    fragmentShader  : document.getElementById( 'fragment_shader' ).textContent
});
```

And this to apply it to the object:

```
object.children[1].material = AvatarTextureF;
```

I have tried a few ways, including just using a normal material:

```
var AvatarTextureF = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('./Avatar/FaceTestTr.png'), shininess: 80, color: 0xffcc66, shading: THREE.SmoothShading, alphaMap: 0x000000} );
```

With the same result.

Here is the updated code, now the head is just invisible..

[Invisible head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJtSZ.png)

Shaders:

```
    <script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertex_shader">
   #if NUM_DIR_LIGHTS > 0
   struct DirectionalLight {
     vec3 direction;
   vec3 color;
  int shadow;
   float shadowBias;
  float shadowRadius;
  vec2 shadowMapSize;
  };
 uniform DirectionalLight directionalLights[ NUM_DIR_LIGHTS ];
 #endif
 //varying vec3 color;
 void main() {
 float r = directionalLights[0].color.r;
 //color = vec3(r,0.6,0.6,0.6);
 gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position , 1.0); }
 </script>


 <script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragment_shader">
  uniform vec3 color;
 uniform sampler2D texture;

 varying vec2 vUv;
   void main() {
   vec4 tColor = texture2D( texture, vUv );
  gl_FragColor = vec4( mix( color, tColor.rgb, tColor.a ), 1.0 );
   }
 </script>
```

And the head:

```
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('./Avatar/FaceTestTr.png'); 
                        texture.needsUpdate = true;

                        // uniforms

                        var uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.merge( [
                            THREE.UniformsLib[ "lights" ],
                            {
                                color: { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color( 0xffffff ) },
                                texture: { type: "t", value: texture }
                            }



                        ] );

                        // material
                        var AvatarTextureF = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
                            uniforms        : uniforms,
                            vertexShader    : document.getElementById( 'vertex_shader' ).textContent,
                            fragmentShader  : document.getElementById( 'fragment_shader' ).textContent,
                            //transparent: true,
                            lights: true
                        });
```

Comment: the shader that you posed above does not account for shadows, lights, or normals, so will render as a flat color (being either the texture color or the color set on the material determined by the texture alpha)

Answer (score 0):

Did you applied a transparent PNG with the face look?

`gl_FragColor = vec4( mix( color, tColor.rgb, tColor.a ), 1.0 );` will be rendered in `color` value, if `tColor.a` is `0.0`.

That means, it will be painted in white, which you set with `color: { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color( 0xffffff ) }`, except the face look where alpha is `1.0`.

Change the `color` value from `0xffffff` to color you want.

Also you are missing lighting process in your fragment shader.

Comment: So how do I make it so it doesn't paid a color at all, but keeps the original render, and just applies the transparent png ontop of it?

Comment: Can you share the entire code and working example like codepen or jsfiddle?

Comment: Can you try to change the color value, like `0xffff00` where on line 102 of the jsfiddle? then, the face will be yellow I guess. Although the jsfiddle does not work due to lack of resouces

Comment: Also, as 2pha said, adding lighting is very complicated.
Maybe this question is helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35596705/using-lights-in-three-js-shader/35600893#35600893

Comment: I added this `var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('./Avatar/FaceTestTr.png'); 
       texture.needsUpdate = true;
       
       // uniforms
       
       var uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.merge( [
        {
         color: { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color( 0xff0000 ) },
         texture: { type: "t", value: texture }
        },
        THREE.UniformsLib[ "ambient" ],
        THREE.UniformsLib[ "lights" ]
        
        
       
       ] );` 

However it just now renders as black, regardless of what color I make it.

Comment: I get this error in the console, if it helps any. 
three.js:29652 THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error:  0 gl.VALIDATE_STATUS false gl.getProgramInfoLog Varyings with the same name but different type, or statically used varyings in fragment shader are not declared in vertex shader: vUv