# How to correctly set lighting for custom shader material

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl

I have a demo of using a height map in three.js with a custom shader(s).  It works fine (now).  The jsfiddle is [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/richardylewright/7nwpob4y/29/).  the shaders themselves are here:

```
<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        uniform sampler2D   vTexture;
        uniform float       vScale;
        uniform vec3        vLut[ 256 ];

        varying vec3        vColor;

        void main() {

            vec4 heightData = texture2D( vTexture, uv );

            // if the map is grayscale it doesn't matter if you use r, g, or b.
            float vAmount = heightData.r;

            // fetch the color from the lookup table so it gets passed to the fragment shader
            int index = int(heightData.r * 255.0);
            vColor = vLut[index];

            // move the position along the normal
            vec3 newPosition = position + normal * vScale * vAmount;

            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( newPosition, 1.0 );
        }
    </script>

    <script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

        varying vec3  vColor;

        void main() {

            gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor, 1.0);
        }
    </script>
```

The problem is that it is not correctly lit so shading and so on is not right.  I suspect that since I have altered the vertices positions in the shader, I should somehow update the vertex normals, but perhaps it is more than that. I have tried various "*needsUpdating=true" but to no avail.  I have spelunked in the three.js docs and around the web without finding the holy grail.

Any suggestions or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Since you use custom shaders, you need do the lighting calculation by yourself in your shader. This may help you: [Using lights in three.js shader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35596705/using-lights-in-three-js-shader)

here is a full sample for custom lighting([online demo](http://demo.flywithwinds.com/threejs/custom_light.html)):

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/85/three.min.js"> </script>
  <script id="vertShader" type="shader">
varying vec2 vUv;
varying vec3 vecPos;
varying vec3 vecNormal;

void main() {
  vUv = uv;
  // Since the light is in camera coordinates,
  // I'll need the vertex position in camera coords too
  vecPos = (modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0)).xyz;
  // That's NOT exacly how you should transform your
  // normals but this will work fine, since my model
  // matrix is pretty basic
  vecNormal = (modelViewMatrix * vec4(normal, 0.0)).xyz;
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix *
                vec4(vecPos, 1.0);
}
</script>
  <script id="fragShader" type="shader">
precision highp float;

varying vec2 vUv;
varying vec3 vecPos;
varying vec3 vecNormal;

uniform float lightIntensity;
uniform sampler2D textureSampler;

struct PointLight {
  vec3 color;
  vec3 position; // light position, in camera coordinates
  float distance; // used for attenuation purposes. Since
                  // we're writing our own shader, it can
                  // really be anything we want (as long as
                  // we assign it to our light in its
                  // "distance" field
};

uniform PointLight pointLights[NUM_POINT_LIGHTS];

void main(void) {
  // Pretty basic lambertian lighting...
  vec4 addedLights = vec4(0.0,
                          0.0,
                          0.0,
                          1.0);
  for(int l = 0; l < NUM_POINT_LIGHTS; l++) {
      vec3 lightDirection = normalize(vecPos
                            - pointLights[l].position);
      addedLights.rgb += clamp(dot(-lightDirection,
                               vecNormal), 0.0, 1.0)
                         * pointLights[l].color
                         * lightIntensity;
  }
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(textureSampler, vUv)
                 * addedLights;
}
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px;" onload="init()">
<script>
  // standard global variables
  var scene, camera, renderer, textureLoader, light;

  // Character 3d object
  var character = null;

  // FUNCTIONS
  function init() {
    // SCENE
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

    // CAMERA
    var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
    var SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
    var VIEW_ANGLE = 45;
    var ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    var NEAR = 0.1;
    var FAR = 1000;
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT,
      NEAR, FAR);
    scene.add(camera);
    camera.position.set(0,0,5);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);

    // RENDERER
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      antialias:true,
      alpha: true
    });
    renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    var container = document.body;
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    // Create light
    light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1.0);
    // We want it to be very close to our character
    light.position.set(0.0, 0.0, 0.1);
    scene.add(light);

    // Create character
    character = buildCharacter();
    scene.add(character);

    // Start animation
    animate();
  }

  var buildCharacter = (function() {
    var _geo = null;

    // Share the same geometry across all planar objects
    function getPlaneGeometry() {
      if(_geo == null) {
        _geo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1.0, 1.0);
      }

      return _geo;
    };

    return function() {
      var g = getPlaneGeometry();
      var creatureImage = textureLoader.load('g.png');
      creatureImage.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;

      var mat = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        uniforms: THREE.UniformsUtils.merge([
          THREE.UniformsLib['lights'],
          {
            lightIntensity: {type: 'f', value: 1.0},
            textureSampler: {type: 't', value: null}
          }
        ]),
        vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertShader').text,
        fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragShader').text,
        transparent: true,
        lights: true
      });
      // THREE.UniformsUtils.merge() call THREE.clone() on
      // each uniform. We don't want our texture to be
      // duplicated, so I assign it to the uniform value
      // right here.
      mat.uniforms.textureSampler.value = creatureImage;

      var obj = new THREE.Mesh(g, mat);

      return obj;
    }
  })();

  function animate() {
    // Update light profile
    var timestampNow = new Date().getTime()/1000.0;
    var lightIntensity = 0.75 +
      0.25 * Math.cos(timestampNow *
        Math.PI);

    character.material.uniforms
      .lightIntensity.value = lightIntensity;
    light.color.setHSL(lightIntensity, 1.0, 0.5);

    // Render scene
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but I still don't get it.  I spelunked around and found a whole bunch of conflicting info.  I update my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/richardylewright/7nwpob4y/32/) with another try at creating the shaderMaterial and including the lights.  The resulting shaderMaterial (in the debugger) looks OK.  All the right uniform members are there (from lights lib) as well as my custom uniforms (the lut, etc.)  It runs without errors but the plane doesn't get the height info and it is black.  At a guess, the vertex shader aborted? Can anyone point out what I am missing?  TIA.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I copied it and ran it (after faking a g.png).  It works.  So I am studying the code now.  However, I have read some threads here on SO that suggest one can "simply" pass the scene lights to the shader and not have to re-create lights in the shader.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35596705/using-lights-in-three-js-shader), but perhaps I misunderstand.